# Where is the Face key?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

After wandering for forever, I finally found the Face Shrine. Problem is, to get in, I need a key I don't apparently have.

How do I get the Face key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to the Face Shrine is in the *Southern* Face Shrine. To get there from the (locked) dungeon entrance, head south one screen, and then east (right) until there is a break in the bottom wall and you can head south again. From here, follow the path (the Armos statues that block your path can either be pushed or will come to life)
 until you get to the entrance of the Southern Face Shrine, wherein you'll need to defeat a miniboss to obtain the key.

Comment: Side note: You will have problems against this mini-boss if you haven't purchased the Bow from the shop.

Comment: @Powerlord Really? Are we talking about the same miniboss? I seem to recall that the one you need to kill for the key was easily dealt with by charged whirlwind slashes... Granted the last time I played Awakening was well over ten years ago.

Comment: Since community bumped this anyway, iirc I think that only works if you have the level 2 sword.